# Vertically scaling part of an image using Photoshop/Fireworks

Tags: images, editing, adobe-photoshop, graphics, scaling

This is an image of a blackboard:

[image]

I would like to reduce its height while its width, and all its four wooden borders (top, bottom, left, right) should stay unchanged.

Could anyone kindly suggest how this can be done in Photoshop/Fireworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started learning Fireworks (sort of like a lighter, more web-oriented version of Photoshop) a few weeks ago, and I found a pretty cool feature called 9-slice scaling. Basically, you can fix this problem easier in Fireworks with 9-slice scaling. You can tell Fireworks exactly where the borders are located with 9-slice, and scaling it will only scale the parts of the image that **aren't** the borders.

If you need to learn more about 9-slice scaling, just Google it. And you can get a free 30-day trial of Fireworks from Adobe's website.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information.
I will have a look at it and report back later.

Comment: Your suggested method is very useful and it can be done in a minute saving so much time.
Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Not a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got my question answered by [doydot](http://answers.yahoo.com/my/profile;_ylt=AqwGPYwKFt5H5cebgINB4cJz7hR.;_ylv=3?show=436f2d9967202241a1b5b5bd643165f6aa) here, many many thanks to him and his answer should be useful to other people:

> http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100806065111AAMlfW0

**Doydot wrote:**

Each side will have to be separated in order for this to happen (including blackboard)
The left and right borders need shortening by free transform and dragging by the middle not side to keep the width of the border. Do the same for the blackboard. Line everything into place.